card slide animation not occuring on both sides
I wanted to make an animated cared slider similar to the image below for my website:
https://i.ytimg.com/vi/Xh-wIMqohD0/maxresdefault.jpg
Everything is perfectly fine and functioning properly. Except that the cards are not on both the sides. It's only appearing in one side.
I was expecting it to appear on both sides however, It only appears on one side and I can't seem to figure out where the problem is in the code.
Here's the Javascript, HTML, and CSS respectively:


let items = document.querySelectorAll('.slider .item');
let next =  document.getElementById('next');
let prev = document.getElementById('prev');

let active = 3;
function loadshow(){
    let stt = 0;
    items[active].style.transform = `none`;
    items[active].style.zIndex = 1;
    items[active].style.filter = 'none';
    items[active].style.opacity = 1;
    for(var i = active + 1; i < items.length; i++){
      stt++;
      items[i].style.transform = `translateX(${120 * stt}px)scale(${1 - 0.2 * stt}) perspective(16px) rotateY(-1deg)`;
      items[i].style.zIndex = -stt;
      items[i].style.filter = 'blur(5px)';
      items[i].style.opacity = stt > 2 ? 0 : 0.6;
  }
  stt = 0;
  for(var i = active - 1; i >= 0; i--){
    stt++;
    items[i].style.transform = `translateX(${120 * stt}px)scale(${1 - 0.2 * stt}) perspective(16px) rotateY(-1deg)`;
    items[i].style.zIndex = -stt;
    items[i].style.filter = 'blur(5px)';
    items[i].style.opacity = stt > 2 ? 0 : 0.6;
  }
  }
loadshow();
next.onclick = function(){
  active = active + 1 < items.length ? active + 1 : active;
  loadshow();
}

prev.onclick = function(){
  active = active - 1 >= 0 ? active - 1 : active;
  loadshow();
}
.slider{
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 370px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.item{
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 320px;
  text-align: justify;
  background-color: #5d5d5d;
  /*backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(10px);*/
  border-radius: 8px;
  padding: 20px;
  transition: 0.5s;
  left: calc(50% - 110px);
  top: 0;
}

#next, #prev{
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  font-size: 50px;
  font-family: 'cabinet Grotesk', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  left: 30px;
}

#next{
  left: unset;
  right: 30px;

}
<div class="slider">
    <div class="item">
        <h1>card7</h1>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Animi impedit quibusdam qui. Adipisci fugit perspiciatis corporis culpa, repellat illum autem nobis earum id modi beatae cupiditate obcaecati praesentium vitae magnam aspernatur officia perferendis, maiores a alias hic quae dolores. Dicta?
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <h1>Card6</h1>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Animi impedit quibusdam qui. Adipisci fugit perspiciatis corporis culpa, repellat illum autem nobis earum id modi beatae cupiditate obcaecati praesentium vitae magnam aspernatur officia perferendis, maiores a alias hic quae dolores. Dicta?
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <h1>card5</h1>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Animi impedit quibusdam qui. Adipisci fugit perspiciatis corporis culpa, repellat illum autem nobis earum id modi beatae cupiditate obcaecati praesentium vitae magnam aspernatur officia perferendis, maiores a alias hic quae dolores. Dicta?
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <h1>Card1</h1>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Animi impedit quibusdam qui. Adipisci fugit perspiciatis corporis culpa, repellat illum autem nobis earum id modi beatae cupiditate obcaecati praesentium vitae magnam aspernatur officia perferendis, maiores a alias hic quae dolores. Dicta?
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <h1>card2</h1>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Animi impedit quibusdam qui. Adipisci fugit perspiciatis corporis culpa, repellat illum autem nobis earum id modi beatae cupiditate obcaecati praesentium vitae magnam aspernatur officia perferendis, maiores a alias hic quae dolores. Dicta?
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <h1>card3</h1>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Animi impedit quibusdam qui. Adipisci fugit perspiciatis corporis culpa, repellat illum autem nobis earum id modi beatae cupiditate obcaecati praesentium vitae magnam aspernatur officia perferendis, maiores a alias hic quae dolores. Dicta?
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <h1>card4</h1>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Animi impedit quibusdam qui. Adipisci fugit perspiciatis corporis culpa, repellat illum autem nobis earum id modi beatae cupiditate obcaecati praesentium vitae magnam aspernatur officia perferendis, maiores a alias hic quae dolores. Dicta?
    </div>
    <button id="next">></button>
    <button id="prev"><</button>
</div>




It's hard to determine what you intend to achieve. Can you create a snippet inside your question so we could see what the situation is?

impressive design!
Whilst you have correctly positioned cards 4 (middle), 5, 6 and 7 (right-most card), by applying tranform=none [which is equivalent to translateX(0)], translateX(120px), translateX(240px) and translateX(360px), respectively, you have not applied the correct transformation on card 3, 2, and 1 (first/left-most card).
In other words, you have used the same transformation on cards 3, 2, and 1, as you did on cards 5, 6 and 7, resulting in these cards overlapping on the right side.
Instead, what you should do is translate cards 3, 2, and 1, in the opposite direction by transforming and applying the appropriate negative offset to these items, i.e, translateX(-360px), translateX(-240px) and translateX(-120px), respectively. Remember, the translateX() CSS function works like a mirror across a Cartesian Y-axis (if you did a bit of pure Maths in school...).
Also, please note that the opacity of cards 3, 2, and 1 should be set to 1, NOT zero, as you currently have it, which makes these cards completely transparent. Hope this helps!
